# Remove everything from comment except certain string

Tags: python, bots, strip, reddit, praw

So I've made a bot for Reddit that listens for a specific string that calls the bot into action. Well call that string, "`!callme`". When you use this bot, you must provide a number after the call string, such as "`!callme 1234`".

Currently, I have the bot set to remove "`!callme`" and the spaces in the string, and if anything else exists after that, it posts a "failed" comment and tells the user to try again. What I want to do is have it remove literally everything from the comment **EXCEPT** the number string after the "`!callme`" string. I need this because it uses the number in a mathematical operation, and if the final value isn't a digit, it fails and tells the user they did it wrong.

For example: "`!callme 12345`" would work and post the correct comment, but "`!callme helloworld`" would fail and post the comment telling them the correct format.

I want to skip that step and strip everything but the number string after the "!callme" string. Basically, if the user writes a sentence before calling the bot, it would fail. I want to change that.

The code I have now is below for the current working strip.

```
g = comment.body
        pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
        g = re.sub(pattern, '', g)
        g = g.replace('!callme', '')
        if g.isdigit():
            g = int(g)
        else:
            bad comment here
            data_entry(com_id, com_auth, 1)
            print("Bad comment found! Posting reply to comment " + comment.id + "!")
        if isinstance(g, int):
            cp = float(g / 100)
            pa = float(cp / 10)
            good comment here
```

There's some other `try` statements with the comments, but that doesn't matter for this.

How could I go about doing this? Also if this code here is not optimal, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly, would something like this fit?

```
g = "!callme XXX"
pat = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
num = re.findall(pat, g) # num = []
g = "!callme 1234"
num = re.findall(pat, g) # num = '1234', now you could int(num)
```

or you can use a more precise regex such as

```
g = "!callme   1234" 
pat = re.compile(r'(\!callme[ ]*)([0-9]+)')
m = re.search(pat, g)
# and go directly to group 2 which should be the num
print m.group(2) # this prints 1234, then int(m.group(2))
```

Here i define two groups, one for the callme part and the other for the numeric part

Answer (score 0):

This should match the number you want.

```
pattern = re.compile(".*!callme +(\d+).*")
result = re.findall(pattern, g)
if result:
    g = int(result[0])
```

Pattern explanation:`.*!callme +(\d+).*`
`.*` match anything before `!callme`
`+` match at least one space after `!callme`
`(\d+)` match at least one digit
`.*` match any chars after